# Font Awesome icon not showing, but other do

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I've seen a lot of people with this problem, but they all had different solutions but none has worked for me.
I've tried changing "fa" to "fas" and "fab", I've imported a bunch of CDNs, files, all.css, links and none worked. But it works for some icons.
For example, this one works:

```
<i class="fas fa-scissors"></i>
```

but this one doesn't:

```
<i class="fas fa-person-fill"></i>
```

How can I solve this?

I've tried changing "fa" to "fas" and "fab", I've imported a bunch of CDNs, files, all.css, links and none worked. But it works for some icons.
For example, this one works:

```
<i class="fas fa-scissors"></i>
```

but this one doesn't:

```
<i class="fas fa-person-fill"></i>
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: what if you delete the `fill`? like this `<i class="fas fa-person"></i>
`  it's working

Comment: @Dhaifallah doesn't work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `fill` after the icon name is a `bootstrap` thing but you need to change the `fa` or `fas` to `bi`

see the available icons for [bootstrap](https://icons.getbootstrap.com/) and [font-awesome](https://fontawesome.com/v5/search)

here is how you can use both font awesome and bootstrap icons:

```html
<!--  Font Awesome cdn -->
<link rel="stylesheet" 
 href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css">


<!--  Bootstrap cdn -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">


 
<h5>font awesome Icon :</h5>
<i class="fa fa-person"></i>

<h5>Bootstrap Icon :</h5>
<i class="bi bi-person-fill"></i>
```

Comment: I had tried changing it to "bi bi-person-fill" but I didn't work, however, it seems like I was missing the bootstrap CDN, so thank you :)

Comment: @patsilva you are welcome, happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the "fill" as part of the name -the "FAS" prefix stands for "Font Awesome SOLID" - so its filled in by default

```html
<!--  Font Awesome cdn -->
<link rel="stylesheet" 
 href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css">
 
 <p>fas fa-scissors</p>
<i class="fas fa-scissors"></i>

<p>fas fa-person</p>
<i class="fas fa-person"></i>
```

Comment: I had tried "fa-person" already and it didn't work, however, the link you provided was what's missing, the one I had was probably outdated.